# Firebird SQL join tables

Tags: sql, firebird

Currently I have tables like these:

Table Customer

```
ID      Name
01      Angel
02      Charlie
```

Table Input1

```
Name     Value
Charlie  5
Angel    7
Charlie  10
Angel    3
```

Table Input2

```
Name     Value
Charlie  10
Angel    5
Charlie  15
Angel    25
```

How to get result like this

```
Name     Input1     Input2
Angel    10         30
Charlie  15         25
```

Comment: What have you tried this far?

Comment: Please use ID column for foreign key anyway, not Name!

Comment: @BálintBudavölgyi I'm sorry I'm newbie at SQL. I tried something like SELECT Customer.Name, Input1.Value as Input1, Input2.Value as Input2 FROM Customer LEFT JOIN Input1 ON Customer.Name=Input1.Name LEFT JOIN Input2 ON Customer.Name=Input2.Name GROUP BY Name 

But it gave me an error.

Comment: @BigBother Is it make query faster if we use ID column for foreign key?

Comment: Faster join and smaller indexes, but the main point is maintainability (name can change if you have mispelled it for example)

Comment: @MochFahmyAinurRofiq I forgot to reply directly to you in my last comment so this is just to notify you...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    c.Name, 
    i1."Value" value1, 
    i2."Value" value2
FROM 
    Customer c LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT Name, SUM("Value") "Value" from input1 group by Name) i1
    ON c.Name = i1.Name LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT Name, SUM("Value") "Value" from input2 group by Name) i2
    ON c.Name = i2.Name
```

**DEMO**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/204220/2

Comment: `Value`is a reserved word in Firebird. Please consider change column name or put it between double quotes (if you do the latter please note that it will be case sensitive)

Comment: @BigBother Yes, of course, its just an example. On my apps the tables using Capitalized column and named using my native language, so no reserved word used as column name. :)